# How do I use `yy_bs_lineno` and `yy_bs_column` in Flex?

Tags: flex-lexer

In the generated C code from Flex, I see that `YY_BUFFER_STATE` is declared as the following

```
struct yy_buffer_state
{
    ...
    int yy_bs_lineno; /**< The line count. */
    int yy_bs_column; /**< The column count. */
    ...
}
```

I would like to announce lexing errors to the user along with the line number and column of the incorrect token, but the `yy_bs_lineno` and `yy_bs_column` fields aren't touched anywhere after being initialized to 1 and 0, respectively. Do I need to increment these myself somewhere in my lexing definitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data members of the `flex` buffer state are private; you shouldn't try to use them. In particular, the `yy_bs_lineno` and `yy_bs_column` members are used by `flex` in reentrant scanners.

If you use:

```
%option yylineno
```

then `flex` will keep track of the current line number in the variable `yylineno`.

Note that `yylineno` is the line number of the line of the first character following the token. So if the token includes (or even ends with) a newline character, `yylineno`'s value will be a little deceptive. If you have multi-line tokens (multi-line string constants, for example) then it's worthwhile keeping the previous value of `yylineno` around.

`Flex` is pretty clever about line counting. It knows which tokens cannot match newline characters, for example, so it doesn't need to rescan input after it finds one of those tokens. It's almost always a good idea to let flex do the work for you.

Unfortunately, there is no similar simple way of tracking columns, but there are a couple of things which help. One of them is the macro hook `YY_USER_ACTION`. If you define this macro, it will be executed just before every action. So you can use that to keep your line number information in sync.

Here's the simplest example I could cut-and-paste:

```
%{
#  include <stdio.h>

/* WARNINGS:
 *   1. Reentrant scanners define yycolumn
 *      Only use this in a non-reentrant scanner
 *   2. This will not work if you use `yyless()` or `yymore()`.
 */
int yycolumn = 1;

/* Forward declarations */
void report(const char* ttype, int line, int column);

/* This is executed before every action. */
#define YY_USER_ACTION                                                   \
  start_line = prev_yylineno; start_column = yycolumn;                   \
  if (yylineno == prev_yylineno) yycolumn += yyleng;                     \
  else {                                                                 \
    for (yycolumn = 1; yytext[yyleng - yycolumn] != '\n'; ++yycolumn) {} \
    prev_yylineno = yylineno;                                            \
  }

%}
%option noyywrap nounput noinput
%option yylineno

%%
   /* Any indented text before the first rule goes at the top of the lexer.  */
   int start_line, start_column;
   int prev_yylineno = yylineno;

[[:space:]]+              { }
[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]* { report("ID", start_line, start_column);
                            return 258; 
                          }
["]([^"]|\\.)*["]         { report("STR", start_line, start_column);
                            return 259;
                          }
.                         { report("SYM", start_line, start_column);
                            return yytext[0];
                          }
%%
void report(const char* t, int l, int c) {
  printf("Encountered %s \"%.*s\" at %d:%d\n", t, (int)yyleng, yytext, l, c);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  while (yylex() > 0) {}
  return 0;
}
```